# Looking for an analogy to describe a place as your playground?

Tags: analogy

I saw a line in writing that said “Google is my playground.” Essentially a place that gives them the reins to excersize their passions.

Does anyone know of a similar analogy?

Comment: Google is my wonderland.

Comment: Google is my _stamping ground_ . [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stamping%20ground).

Answer (score 1):

"Like  kid in a candy store" is an expression that indicates a person is involved in an activity they find pleasurable. The pleasure may be derived from being free to indulge a hobby, as when an antique collector finds unexpectedly a gigantic store for antiques and has an entire day to indulge their love for antiques.

Another example could be a person--a child of the 60s--who has been given a very large collection of classic rock records from the 1960s. They have an entire weekend to go through the collection. A good friend of this person might remark, "Boy, they're like a kid in a candy store!"